# Exporting Data to Excel in MVC

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, model-view-controller

I have successfully exported data from a gridview to Excel for a single worksheet but I want to add multiple worksheets. I have googled around and tried a few options but nothing is quite working but I am getting close. I think it is a matter of just a few lines of code. Now I have the following code:

```
  public ActionResult Download()
    {
        if (Session["BP"] != null)
        {
            return new DownloadFileActionResult((GridView)Session["BP"], "BestPrices.xls");
        }
        else
        {
            return new JavaScriptResult();
        }
    }
```

I populate the session variable using a datable and gridview:

```
  GridView gv = new GridView();
       gv.DataSource = gridTable;

         gv.DataBind();
     //    Session["BP"] = myGridViews;
         Session["BP"] = g;
```

I have built an array of gridviews thinking that would help but I cannot export that now.

```
        GridView[] g = new GridView[retailerTables.Count];
        int n = 0;
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            myGridViews[n] = retailerTables[key];
            g[n] = new GridView();
            g[n].DataSource = retailerTables[key];
            g[n].DataBind();
            n++;


        }
```

My basic idea is that each worksheet in the excel file corresponds to one gridview.

I have seen various third party options but I do not know how reliable they are and if I will end up debugging  interface errors. I prefer to use the core classes and options in MVC.

The application is running on a website and the user will click a link to download the file.

The retailer tables are:

```
 Dictionary<string,  DataTable> retailerTables= new Dictionary<string,  DataTable>();
```

Hence each worksheet will have sales data for a retailer and the user can finally just click on different retailers and see the sales data.

Does anyone know how to solve the issue to exporting multiple tables to excel as I have outlined.

Comment: You don't want to use the Excel COM components for anything on a Web server. They weren't designed for use there, and a multitude of errors can happen. I have used [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) on many projects, and it works very well. It's very easy to work with, and handles multiple worksheets with ease.

Comment: What @krillgar said. I generally use [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) for my Excel needs and have had no complaints.

Comment: I solved using NPOI. I will post the code later.

Answer (score 1):

I used nuget to install npoi. I used for the using statements:

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;  
using NPOI.HSSF.Util;


 public void DataTablesToXls(Dictionary<string,  DataTable> retailerTables, String filename, String allName)
    {

        var keys = new List<string>(retailerTables.Keys);
        HSSFWorkbook xlsWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        IFont hlink_font = xlsWorkBook.CreateFont();
        ICellStyle hlink_style = xlsWorkBook.CreateCellStyle();

        HSSFFont bestpriceFont = (HSSFFont)xlsWorkBook.CreateFont();
        HSSFCellStyle bestpriceStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)xlsWorkBook.CreateCellStyle();
        bestpriceFont.Color = HSSFColor.Blue.Index;
        bestpriceStyle.FillForegroundColor = HSSFColor.Blue.Index;
        bestpriceStyle.SetFont(bestpriceFont);


        HSSFFont priceFont = (HSSFFont)xlsWorkBook.CreateFont();
        HSSFCellStyle priceStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)xlsWorkBook.CreateCellStyle();
        priceFont.Color = HSSFColor.Red.Index;
        bestpriceStyle.FillForegroundColor = HSSFColor.Red.Index;
        priceStyle.SetFont(priceFont);

        HSSFFont matchFont = (HSSFFont)xlsWorkBook.CreateFont();
        HSSFCellStyle matchStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)xlsWorkBook.CreateCellStyle();
        matchFont.Color = HSSFColor.Green.Index;
        matchStyle.FillForegroundColor = HSSFColor.Green.Index;
        matchStyle.SetFont(matchFont);

        HSSFFont ordinaryFont = (HSSFFont)xlsWorkBook.CreateFont();
        HSSFCellStyle ordinaryStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)xlsWorkBook.CreateCellStyle();
        ordinaryFont.Color = HSSFColor.Black.Index;
        ordinaryStyle.FillForegroundColor = HSSFColor.Black.Index;
        ordinaryStyle.SetFont(ordinaryFont);
        Dictionary<string, HSSFCellStyle> fonts = new Dictionary<string,HSSFCellStyle>();
         fonts.Add("best", bestpriceStyle);
         fonts.Add("price", priceStyle);
         fonts.Add("match", matchStyle);
         fonts.Add("ordinary", ordinaryStyle);


        string keyFont = "ordinary";
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            if (!(@key.Equals(allName)))
            {


                DataTable dt = retailerTables[key];


                ISheet retailerWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.CreateSheet(@key);


                IRow header = retailerWorkSheet.CreateRow(0);

                int rcount = 0;
                int colCount = 0;

                colCount = 0;
                IRow rheader = retailerWorkSheet.CreateRow(rcount);
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine(row[column]);

                    ICell c = rheader.CreateCell(colCount);
                    // c.SetCellValue(dt.Rows[0][column].ToString());
                    c.SetCellValue(@column.ToString());

                    colCount++;
                }

                Boolean matchRow = false;
                rcount++;
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    colCount = 0;
                    IRow r = retailerWorkSheet.CreateRow(rcount);

                    Boolean bestpriceRow = false;
                    if (allName.Equals("all"))
                    {
                        if (row[dt.Columns[2]].Equals(@key))   // handling all data 
                        {
                            bestpriceRow = true;
                            keyFont = "best";
                        } else {
                            keyFont = "price";
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        // Console.WriteLine(row[column]);

                        HSSFCell c = (HSSFCell)r.CreateCell(colCount);
                       // retailerWorkSheet.AutoSizeColumn(column.Ordinal);


                        String rowVal = row[column].ToString();
                        if (allName.Equals("none")) {
                            if (row[dt.Columns[3]].Equals(rowVal))   // handling all data 
                            {
                                bestpriceRow = false; // show in red
                                matchRow = true;
                                keyFont = "match";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bestpriceRow = false;
                                matchRow = false;
                                keyFont="ordinary";
                            }


                        }
                        //        if (@key.Equals("all"))
                        //        {
                        //     hlink_font.Color = HSSFColor.Black.Index;
                        //     hlink_style.SetFont(hlink_font);

                        //       } else {
                   //     if (rowVal.Equals(@key))
                   //     {
                   //         bestpriceRow = true;
                  //      }

                        //       }


                        if (rowVal != null)
                        {
                            if (rowVal.IndexOf("=HYPERLINK") != -1)
                            {
                                string[] celldata = new string[2];
                                celldata = getCellData(rowVal);

                               // rowVal.IndexOf("\""); 

                              //  rowVal = rowVal.Replace("=HYPERLINK", "");
                                //rowVal = rowVal.Replace("(", "");
                               // rowVal = rowVal.Replace(")", "");
                              //  rowVal = rowVal.Replace("\",\"", ";");
                             //   string[] words = rowVal.Split(';');
                                if (celldata!=null)
                                {
                               //     string cellValue = words[1];
                                    string cellLink = celldata[0];
                               //     cellValue = cellValue.Replace("\"", "");
                                 //   cellLink = cellLink.Replace("\"", "");
                                    string cellValue = celldata[1];
                                    HSSFHyperlink link = new HSSFHyperlink(HyperlinkType.Url);
                                    link.Address = cellLink;
                                    c.SetCellValue(cellValue);
                                    c.Hyperlink = (link);
                                    c.CellStyle= fonts[@keyFont];
                               /*     if (bestpriceRow)
                                    {

                                        c.CellStyle = bestpriceStyle;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (matchRow)
                                        {
                                            c.CellStyle = matchStyle;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            c.CellStyle = priceStyle;
                                        }
                                    } */

                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                c.SetCellValue(row[column].ToString());
                                   c.CellStyle= fonts[@keyFont];
                             /*   if (bestpriceRow)
                                {

                                    c.CellStyle = bestpriceStyle;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (matchRow)
                                    {
                                        c.CellStyle = matchStyle;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        c.CellStyle = priceStyle;
                                    }
                                } */

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            c.SetCellValue(row[column].ToString());
                            c.CellStyle= fonts[@keyFont];
                           /* if (bestpriceRow)
                            {

                                c.CellStyle = bestpriceStyle;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (matchRow)
                                {
                                    c.CellStyle = matchStyle;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    c.CellStyle = priceStyle;
                                }
                            } */

                        }

                        colCount++;
                    }
                    rcount++;
                }


            }

          //  retailerTables[key] 
        }

        string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/data");
        string datafile = Path.Combine(folderPath, filename);


        FileStream file = new FileStream(datafile, FileMode.CreateNew);
        xlsWorkBook.Write(file);
        file.Close();


    }
```